# How can I get this video to play inline?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Phonegap app that allows me to paste a video link and embed the video using [embed.ly](http://embed.ly/). I would like the video to play inline and not go to fullscreen. I understand that adding a "webkit-playsinline" to a video tag should work however, I'm not sure of how I can make webkit-playsinline work with the iframe that embedly adds the video to. This is what my code looks like. I have tried to add comments and be as clear as possible:

```
<script>
    $.embedly.defaults.key = 'mykeyhere';
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = urlaft; //Contains my url to video
        var urladd = '<li><a href="' + url + '"></a></li>'; //adds url to a <a> element within an li 
        document.getElementById("videobox").innerHTML = urladd; //appends li with video link to ul
        $('a').embedly({
            query: {
                maxheight: 195
            },
            'method': 'after'
        }); //using embedly to turn the <a> link into an embedded video
        $('.embedly-embed').attr('webkit-playsinline', ''); //This was my attempt at adding a webkit-playsinline to the iframe that embedly has added the video to.
    });
</script>
```

The code above fails to produce the results I'm looking for. I would like to play videos that are embedded inline.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the autoplay parameter in the embedly request. Additionaly you have to enable playing videos automatically in your phonegap app, e.g. for Android:

```
super.appView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```